# Preserve "\t", "\n", "\r" when spliting a string using shlex in python

Tags: python, split, shlex

I am trying to split a string using shlex but I want to preserve(literally) "\t", "\n", "\r".

Example:

```
text = "a=\t\n\r\example c=d"
sp_text = shlex.split(text)
print(sp_text)

['a=', 'example', 'c=d']
```

But I want to print this:

```
['a=\t\n\r\example', 'c=d']
```

Can I do that using shlex?

/Angelos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import shlex

text = "a=\t\n\r\example c=d"

sh = shlex.shlex(text)
sh.whitespace = ' '
sh.whitespace_split = True

sp_text = list(sh)
print(sp_text)
```

**Output**

```
['a=\t\n\r\\example', 'c=d']
```

Notice that the example above only uses the single whitespace for splitting, the idea of the example is to illustrate how to manipulate the shlex whitespace.